# Get SUM another table off all rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have database value, for example

`table name: a_table`

```
===================================
| userId       | userName         |
===================================
===================================
| abc          | Alice            |
| bcd          | Rachel           |
| efg          | Raymond          |
===================================
```

`table name: b_transaction`

```
=============================================
| transCode     | userId       | value      |
=============================================
=============================================
| 1             | abc          | 100        |
| 2             | abc          | -200       |
| 3             | abc          | 300        |
=============================================
```

My goal is, get sum of all data, if user dont have row in table transaction, they must be 0. But when I try this query

```
SELECT a.userId, a.userName, SUM(b.value)
FROM a_table a
LEFT JOIN b_transaction b ON a.userId = b.userId
```

The result just return 1 row

```
================================================
| userId       | userName         | value      |
================================================
================================================
| abc          | Alice            | 200        |
================================================
```

How to achieve that?
Thaanks~

Comment: you need to add at the end of query, GROUP BY a.userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add group by:

```
SELECT a.userId, a.userName, IFNULL (SUM(b.value),0)
FROM a_table a
LEFT JOIN b_transaction b ON a.userId = b.userId
GROUP BY  a.userId, a.userName
```

see the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f9afa/3)

Answer (score 2):

You could try grouping the results on the users over the summing of the transactions, like this?

```
SELECT a.userId, a.userName, SUM(b.value)
FROM a_table a
LEFT JOIN b_transaction b ON a.userId = b.userId
GROUP BY a.userId, a.userName
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple group by statement in your SQL should create the desired result for example:

```sql
SELECT a.userId, a.userName, SUM(b.value)
FROM a_table a
LEFT JOIN b_transaction b ON a.userId = b.userId GROUP BY a.userId
```

Comment: Always groub all columns that are part of the `SELECT` clause. Else you get an error in most databases

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IFNULL` to check if the result of the sum is null (that is the case if there is no reference for a row from a to b) or not, and then apply a default value :

```
SELECT a.userId, a.userName, IFNULL(SUM(b.value), 0) AS 'Sum'
FROM a_table a
LEFT JOIN b_transaction b ON a.userId = b.userId
GROUP BY a.userId, a.userName
```

This outputs :

```
| userId | userName | Sum |
| ------ | -------- | --- |
| abc    | Alice    | 200 |
| bcd    | Rachel   | 0   |
| efg    | Raymond  | 0   |
```

Comment: I think this is not correct  `IFNULL(SUM(b.value), 0) it should be SUM (IF(b.value is not null, b.value, 0))` because you are overriding 'Sum' value

Comment: @Zeljka [This is correct](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/CP1wMpKi6ptqkPyq6iR4/0)